# Autoinstall Lubuntu

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, autoinstall

I successfully was able to autoinstall Ubuntu Server 22.04 by calling following GRUB commands. `<my-server>` provides a `user-data` config file where users will be created etc.

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz 
autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;seedfrom=<my-server>/ ---
boot
```

**Is it possible to do the same for Lubuntu 22.04?**

Lubuntu doesn't seem to respect the `autoinstall` command. Instead, it directly boots into live mode.
If not, I guess my best option is to stick to Ubuntu Server and just install all packages Lubuntu comes with. Or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: I can't speak with authority here sorry, but you want features that exist in ISOs that use the *debian installer*, `ubiquity` and `subiquity`, but no effort has been made to make those features work with `calamares` for the *flavors* that use it; as they are intended for single install by desktop users.  There is no `autoinstall` feature in those ISOs as there isn't intended to be one. If I wanted it, I'd use a server install as you mentioned.   (*you may get responses from others with more knowledge than me in time*)

Comment: FYI: on last comment & my mention of "*speaking with authority*"... I'm a Lubuntu Council member, so have a *reasonable* understanding of Lubuntu, an excellent idea of what we QA test, and what *works*, is *expected to work* & what "doesn't work* thus my comment.. but the ~six folks with "*authority*" to provide an answer consist of ~5 that don't use this site, so there is good chance you'll not get more than my prior comment.. ie.  We/Lubuntu are aware of issues like this, [OEM](https://phab.lubuntu.me/T16) etc we'd like to offer.. but with a small team of volunteers we can only do so much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak with authority here sorry, but you want features that exist in ISOs that use the *debian installer*, `ubiquity` and `subiquity`, but no effort has been made to make those features work with `calamares` for the [*two*] *flavors* that use it; as they are intended for single install by desktop users. There is no autoinstall feature in those ISOs as there isn't intended to be one.

If I wanted it, I'd use a Ubuntu Server install as you mentioned. (*you may get responses from others with more knowledge than me in time*)

FYI: My mention of "*speaking with authority*"... I'm a Lubuntu Council member, so have a *reasonable* understanding of Lubuntu, an *excellent* idea of what we QA (*Quality Assurance*) test, and what works, is expected to work & what "*doesn't work*" thus my comment.. but the ~six *folks* with "*authority*" to provide an answer consist of ~5 that don't use this site, so there is good chance you'll not get more than my prior comment..

ie. We/Lubuntu are aware of issues like this, [OEM](https://phab.lubuntu.me/T16) etc we'd like to offer.. but with a small team of volunteers we can only do so much.

Comment: this answer is just my prior comments combined..  (*slight wording changes*)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights. I ended up using Ubuntu Server and installing all Lubuntu packages that are important to me. Works really well.